# Complex rows partitioning

Tags: oracle, rows, partitioning

I got a issue, i cant figure out how to do it. But firstly, i'll show you the table example. The real one is much more complex. BUt lets back to issue.

```
select id, value, value2, date from boards

ID    VALUE    VALUE2  DATE
1     A        Z       2014
2     A        Z       2015
3     B        Z       2015
4     B        C       2015
5     A        Z       2016
```

Date is not important (its only for correct row ordering). Results i get when execute query. Its not the results i want.

```
SELECT a.
  FROM SELECT id,
              VALUE,
              value2,
              DATE,
             row_number() over(PARTITION BY VALUE, value2 ORDER BY DATE) ranking
        FROM boards)
    WHERE a.ranking = 1

ID    VALUE    VALUE2  DATE
1     A        Z       2014
3     B        Z       2015
4     B        C       2015
```

Output is right. But it's not right results i want. My desire that it should be like that:

```
ID    VALUE    VALUE2  DATE
1     A        Z       2014
3     B        Z       2015
4     B        C       2015
5     A        Z       2016
```

Is there any way, i could get the results i want ? using others functions, making complex logic. All suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't see a query, and it is not clear to me whence either the expected or current result set is from.  Please add your query and logic to the question.

Comment: I edited the post, i hope it much more clear

Comment: It still isn't clear, because just adding `ROW_NUMBER` to your select statement should _not_ be changing the number of rows coming back.  Do you have a hidden `WHERE` clause which you forgot to include?

Comment: i did it again. :) how about now ?

Comment: Your current output is correct, and the logic for why only one of the two A-Z records is removed is still not clear.

Comment: I understand that output is right. I need output to be like the last block of code :)

Comment: The last column is a date type column? or an integer containing years?

Comment: It is a DATE type column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Tabibitosan technique. I assume here you have already extracted year from the date column. But logic remains the same even if you use the whole date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c19a1/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE boards
    (ID int, VALUE1 varchar2(1), VALUE2 varchar2(1), DATE_t int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO boards (ID, VALUE1, VALUE2, DATE_t)
         VALUES (1, 'A', 'Z', 2014)
    INTO boards (ID, VALUE1, VALUE2, DATE_t)
         VALUES (2, 'A', 'Z', 2015)
    INTO boards (ID, VALUE1, VALUE2, DATE_t)
         VALUES (3, 'B', 'Z', 2015)
    INTO boards (ID, VALUE1, VALUE2, DATE_t)
         VALUES (4, 'B', 'C', 2015)
    INTO boards (ID, VALUE1, VALUE2, DATE_t)
         VALUES (5, 'A', 'Z', 2016)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
  SELECT MIN (ID) AS ID,
         VALUE1,
         VALUE2,
         MIN (DATE_T) as "DATE"
    FROM (SELECT b.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DATE_T)
                 - ROW_NUMBER ()
                      OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE1, VALUE2 ORDER BY DATE_T)
                    seq
            FROM boards b)
GROUP BY VALUE1, VALUE2, seq
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c19a1/11/0)**:

```
| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | DATE |
|----|--------|--------|------|
|  1 |      A |      Z | 2014 |
|  3 |      B |      Z | 2015 |
|  4 |      B |      C | 2015 |
|  5 |      A |      Z | 2016 |
```

Comment: Thank you! i appreciate it.

Comment: I think I would changed the `MIN(id)` to be `MIN(id) keep (dense_rank first order by date_t)`, especially if the row with the lowest id does not correspond to the row with the lowest date in the group.

Comment: @KaushikNayak did it